# HTML Attachments opened in Apple device not showing some images

Tags: html, ios

I am wondering if someone can help me with a problem I am encountering with iPhone/iPad. I have an email the generates a report as an HTML attachment. In that HTML attachment, there are two images. One is a static image that pulls down a logo using a normal HTML img tag.

The other is dynamic. It also uses the normal HTML img tag, however it calls out to a web api with some information identifying the user.

```
<img src="http://MyApiServerName.com/api/User/{id}/{OtherParm}" >
```

The Web API uses information on the user to return appropriate images to them. For some reason the dynamic image does not show up with the attachment is opened on an iPad/iPhone.

The image works just fine when the attachment is opened from a computer. I thought maybe something might be blocking images, however then I would expect the static image not to display as well. I verified that the "Load Remote Images" setting is turned on.

I am at a loss here. Is there something with iOS that prevents dynamically generated images from showing in HTML attachments?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can't explain why the above is not working, but I did find something that does. Instead of using the following URL

```
<img src="http://MyApiServerName.com/api/User/{id}/{OtherParm}" >
```

use

```
<img src="http://MyApiServerName.com/api/User/{id}/{OtherParm.jpg}/" >
```

The final param needs to end with ".jpg/". If the slash is not there, you will get a 404 error.

Then in the API method, you simply strip off the .jpg part of "OtherParm" to get the intended value for "OtherParm".